# bazel build cannot find shared library

Tags: c++, bazel

I have this simple directory structure:

```
.
├── main
│   ├── BUILD
│   └── future.cpp
└── WORKSPACE
```

where the BUILD file is as follow:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

cc_binary(
    name = "future",
    srcs = [
        "future.cpp"
    ],
    copts = [
        "-std=c++1z"
    ],
    linkopts = [
        "-lfolly"
    ]
)
```

When I run the command `bazel build //main:future`, I got the following error message:

```
INFO: Analyzed target //main:future (1 packages loaded, 2 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /home/turtle/projects/miscellaneous/test/cpp/future/main/BUILD:3:10: Linking of rule '//main:future' failed (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc @bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/main/future-2.params

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc @bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/main/future-2.params

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lfolly
```

I made sure that there is a `libfolly.so` under `/usr/local/lib`, and I could compile fine using `g++ main/future.cpp -std=c++1z -lfolly -lboost_context`, so I'm not sure why this error happens. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bazel likes to use the [gold linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_(linker)) instead of GNU ld by default. gold, unlike GNU ld, doesn't put `/usr/local/lib` on the default library search path. This can be remediated by passing `--linkopt=-L/usr/local/lib` to Bazel.